# Laravel User Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

All of my Laravel Model functions located in the User model refuse to work. They all return `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::foo()`. If I make a function in another model, the relationships and everything works. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my entire User.php file.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function seminar()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Seminar');
    }

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

Here is an example of another model in the same project

```
<?php

class Seminar extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'seminar';


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

I am also using the Sentry Cartalyst package

Comment: And where is your `foo` function here? If you have question, tell what exactly you do and what error you get for this particular piece of code.

Comment: The error almost certainly means that you are trying to call `foo` on the QueryBuilder object and not your model. This may be due to not calling `->get()` (or another function that executes a statement) at the end of your query. If it isn't that show us your "foo" function and how you're calling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realized what the error was. I had a migration that has the same classname (User) and that messed up the User model.